# How to return both nested and non-nested fields in a query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with the following mapping:

```
{
  "build": {
    "properties": {
      "info": {
        "properties": {
          "ci": {
            "properties": {
              "generic": {
                "properties": {
                  "job": { ... }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "tests": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "className": { ... }
          "result": {
            "properties": {
              "status": { ... }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What would a query look like that would return the co-associated `info.ci.generic.job` and only the `tests` that match both a query against `info.ci.generic.job` and a nested query against `tests.result.status`?

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `_source` and `inner_hits` will do what you want:

```
{
  "_source": "info.ci.generic",
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "term": {
              "info.ci.generic.job.raw": "my-job-name"
            }
          },
          {
            "nested": {
              "path": "tests",
              "query": {
                "term": {
                  "tests.result.status": "failure"
                }
              },
              "inner_hits": {
                "size": 16777216
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "hits": {
    "hits": [
      {
        "inner_hits": {
          "tests": {
            "hits": {
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_source": {
                      "status": "failure"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "_source": {
          "info": {
            "ci": {
              "generic": {
                "user": "builds",
                "build": "18471",
                "job": "CPIE-family-all-test",
                "host": "http://platform.builds.test.netflix.net/"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```